# Cookies and variables

Tags: php, session, cookies

I've created a login class for my web app and it does work, but now I've created that infamous "keep me logged in" - checkbox and don't get it to work. Here's my class for login:

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

class Login {

    private $error;
    private $connect;
    private $email;
    private $password;
    public $row;

public function __construct(PDO $connect) {

    $this->connect  = $connect;
    $this->error    = array();
    $this->row      = $row;


}

public function doLogin() {

    $this->email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
    $this->password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);
    $this->rememberme = $_POST['rememberme'];

    if($this->validateData()) {

        $this->fetchInfo();

    }

    return count($this->error) ? 0 : 1;

}

public function validateData() {

    if(empty($this->email) || empty($this->password)) {

        $this->error[] = "Täyttämättömiä kenttiä";

    } else {

    return count($this->error) ? 0 : 1;

}

}

public function fetchInfo() {

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email AND  activation_token IS NULL";
    $stmt = $this->connect->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(array(

                ':email' => $this->email,

        )); 



    if($stmt->rowCount() == 0) {
        $this->error[] = "Väärä käyttäjätunnus tai salasana";
        return 0;

    } else {

            $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
                $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
                $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
                $_SESSION['profilepic'] = $row['profilepic'];


            if(isset($this->rememberme)) {
                setcookie("loggedin", "yes", time() + 25200);

            }

    }

    if (Register::cryptPass($this->password) != $row['password']) {
    $this->error[] = "Virheelliset kirjautumistiedot";

    } else {

        return true;

    }
        return count($this->error) ? 0 : 1;

    }



public function displayErrors() {

    if(!count($this->error)) return;
        echo "<div class='login_error'>";
        foreach($this->error as $key=>$value) {
        echo "<p>".$value."</p>";

    }

echo "</div>";

}


public function doLogout() {

    session_destroy();

}

}
?>
```

And here's a small part of my code from my another file where I'm checking if the session or cookie is set:

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['email']) || isset($_COOKIE['loggedin'])) {
?>          
    <div id="header_container_isloggedin">

    <div class="container_12">
    <header id="header">
    <div class="grid-12">

    <ul id="menu">

    <li class="profile-name">

        <a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>">
        <span class="header_username">

    <img src="images/thumbnails/<?php echo $_SESSION['profilepic']; ?>" 
        class="profile_evensmaller"/>

    <span class="header_name"><?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?></span></span></a>

    </li>

</ul>
<?php } ?>
```

The problem is that everytime the cookie is set, it doesn't display my profile picture or name since they've saved inside of $_SESSION variable. So how should I approach this and get this to work. I know that right now it's not the safest method, since I'm not generating any hashes for that cookie, but right now the only thing I'm interested in, is to get this one to work.

Comment: `E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE` --- this is a bad start. Use at least `E_ALL` if you want to grow into a better developer.

Comment: The thing is that you should rely on the cookie only to know if the user should be logged in. Then, if the cookie is valid, you do all the procedure of fetching the data from the database and set the new session.

Comment: So what I'm doing wrong atm? Point me to right direction